# Reacting to Boolean state in reactive ViewModels

Tags: c#, functional-programming, wpf, mvvm, xamarin

When this `ViewModel` loads we kick off the `IsAuthenticatedCommand`:

- If the result of `IsAuthenticatedCommand` is `false` we set the value of `NeedsToLogin` to true.
- If the result of `IsAuthenticatedCommand` is `true` we set the value of `IsAuthenticated` to true.

There are (subscriptions?) to both `NeedsToLogin` and `IsAuthenticated` that are waiting for the true value.

1. Is there a better way to handle this `if`/`else` logic?
2. Should I be worried about race conditions?

```
public class LoadingViewModel : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel {

    private bool _isAuthenticated = false;

    public bool IsAuthenticated {
    get { return _isAuthenticated; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged (ref _isAuthenticated, value); }}


    private bool _needsToLogin;

    public bool NeedsToLogin {
    get { return _needsToLogin; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged (ref _needsToLogin, value); }}

    public ReactiveCommand<bool> IsAuthenticatedCommand { get; protected set; }

    public LoadingViewModel (IScreen screen)
    {
        HostScreen = screen;

        this.WhenAnyValue (x => x.IsAuthenticated)
            .Where (x => x == true)
            .Subscribe (x => { HostScreen.Router.Navigate.ExecuteAsyncTask (new OnboardingViewModel (HostScreen));});

        this.WhenAnyValue (x => x.NeedsToLogin)
            .Where (x => x == true)
            .Subscribe (_ => { HostScreen.Router.Navigate.ExecuteAsyncTask (new LoginViewModel (HostScreen)); });


        //always return false for testing.   
        IsAuthenticatedCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask (async (_) => await Task.Run (() => {return false;}));

        IsAuthenticatedCommand.Subscribe (_ => {
        if (_) { this.IsAuthenticated = true;} else {this.NeedsToLogin = true;}
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: My biggest concern is why you have two bools basically answering the same question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your code neatly; this will improve readability, which will decrease bugs.  First, you have this:

```
public bool IsAuthenticated {
get { return _isAuthenticated; }
set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged (ref _isAuthenticated, value); }}
```

This should be:

```
public bool IsAuthenticated
{
    get { return _isAuthenticated; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged (ref _isAuthenticated, value); }
}
```

The `if`/`else` statement should be written like this:

```
IsAuthenticatedCommand.Subscribe (_ => {
    if (_) { this.IsAuthenticated = true; }
    else { this.NeedsToLogin = true; }
});
```

Also, you need to be consistent with your spacing; sometimes you have a space between braces, sometimes you don't:

```
if (_) { this.IsAuthenticated = true;} else {this.NeedsToLogin = true;}
```

I am no expert at lambda statements, but your lambda with the `if`/`else` looks fine to me.